# how can I adjust volume in my program?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an audio player program in HTML and Javascript. How can I adjust the volume in my program?

Comment: We need more information.  How are you decoding the audio? how are you making the sounds?  What libraries are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the volumne requires access to the operating system's audio device driver or some abstraction layer.

The only way to change the volume is on Windows using ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you're relying on the browser's default plugin to play the audio files. If you're using WMP through object elements, then you could dynamically change the settings using javascript.

```
// get the element's DOM reference, replace to fit needs
obj = document.getElementById("player"); 
// set volume, 0=mute, 100=full
obj.Settings.volume = 50;
```

Combine that with a slider widget (i.e. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)), and that should work.

reference: http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/embed_mediaplayer.htm